# Separated xibs for landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, rotation

I'm very new in ios programing. I'm trying to make a simple form, page based app. I have separated xibs for Landscape\Portrait orientation.  But when I add text in textField and rotate device the text disappears. How do I temporary, dynamically save information of filled fields and when rotate device to fill already filed text fields with information ?

Comment: Hey if your problem is solved then please post your solution here.it will help others.

Comment: I found a solution. When system calls willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method I store already filed textfields in NSMutableDictionary, after rotating, I fill them.

Comment: IBOutletCollection is best for this you don't need to store textfield value, else it's your choice what ever you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may occasionally require separate xibs for landscape and portrait orientations, in general what is actually required is to use layout constraints.

There are two ways you can do this:

- Override layoutSubviews or viewWillLayoutSubViews on a view or controller, and adjust the frame of your child views respective to the bounds of their super-view. To get an understanding of view vs bounds, watch the free Stanford iOS courses on iTunesU (or just fool with it for a while - it will become clear soon enough).
- Use layout constraints.

For non-trivial projects, my personal preference is to develop code-based views, and override layout sub-views, according to the principles [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder).

Answer (score 1):

You should try `GPOrientation`

see here:http://www.logisian.blogspot.in/2012/08/support-landscape-and-portrait-using.html

`GPOrientation` helped me a lot and i am sure it will help you.

For tutorial of GPOrientation see here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=KtVAsLioOEc